# Using lapply to apply a function on a list with different number of element to get different values

Tags: r

This function is the one that I ALMOST need. But the problem that I expect to get different values, that is, I want to calculate run if function for each element of my list. However, as you can see, the function does not calculate it, it just calculates one and repeats the value, such as 1.158114. Do I need to change the if else, or to modify it?

```
L = list(c(F,T),c(F,F,F,T))
VAR = 1
IQ = 3   
lapply(L, function(x){ifelse(x, runif(1, IQ - VAR, IQ + VAR), runif(1,0.20 - VAR , 0.20 + VAR))})

[[1]]
[1] -0.1924877  2.0677188

[[2]]
[1] 1.158114 1.158114 1.158114 2.408010
```

Comment: Change `runif(1, ...)`  to `runif(length(x), ...)`

Comment: The issue here is that ifelse is vectorized, every `T` and `F` are being assigned to the same random uniform value. `lapply` loops over sub-elements of the list. If you want function-ception, you can implement a sapply inside your lapply. `lapply(L, function(x) sapply(x, function(x) ifelse(x, runif(1, IQ - VAR, IQ + VAR), runif(1,0.20 - VAR , 0.20 + VAR))))`  By doing this, you are still looping over the sub-list, but within each sublist, you are looping over each sub-element of the sub-list through sapply. As a result, `ifelse` is now receiving only one value as opposed to a vector.